# 32-bit macro not working on 64-bit excel-sheet? Compile error: module 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel-spreadsheet with a macro created in 32-bit excel, and am now running 64-bit.
I get error message: "Compile error in hidden module: Module1."

I found following solution from https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/compile-error-in-hidden-module-module-1.566811/

1. From the file in question, press Alt + F11 go into its Visual Basic Editor.
2. From the Tools menu select References
3. Scroll through the Available References listbox and untick any that start with MISSING:
4. Press Alt + Q once all of these reference errors have been unticked."

However when I open VBA --> Tools --> References, the "reference" button is greyed out and I'm unable to click on it. Macro's are already disabled, yet still not open to click "reference".

Comment: Is the vba project password protected? If so unprotect it before trying to open the reference menu.

Comment: Also, if the error has appeared before going to the VBE, make sure you completely halt execution - i.e. not just 'Break'. Reference menu remains greyed out in Break mode.